# Which expression is more gas efficient of the following: "2**n" or "1<<n"?

Tags: solidity, gas, optimization

What is the most gas-efficient way to calculate raising 2 to the power of n? Is it power operator (**), or the left bit shift operator (<<)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Ethereum Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) (Appendix G - Fee Schedule), the gas costs for the relevant opcodes are as follows:

- [EXP](https://github.com/wolflo/evm-opcodes/blob/2b745ab5cbfac720967e87c2d545b2dbcec2856a/gas.md#a1-exp): 10 gas (base cost) + 50 gas (per non-zero byte in the exponent)
- [SHL](https://www.evm.codes/#1b): 3 gas

Since the shift left operation (SHL) has a constant gas cost of 3, it is more gas efficient than the exponentiation operation (EXP) which has a base cost of 10 plus an additional 50 gas for each non-zero byte in the exponent. Note that the gas cost for EXP may be even higher depending on the value of n.